# SAS drop multiple variables indexed by tens

Tags: optimization, sas

My question is likely stupid but I have not found an answer yet.
I have a variable *var* index by tens : *var10*, *var20*... *var90*.
At some point of my code I want to drop all of them.

I can do

```
data want(drop=var10 var20 var30 var40 var50 var60 var70 var80 var90);
    set have;
run;
```

I was wondering if there was a more condensed way of doing that. I know if there were variables indexed 10, 11, 12, 13... I could use

```
(drop=var10-90)
```

But as I do not have them, if I use this instruction it still does the job, but with a warning, which is not acceptable for me (I have to create programs that will be used by people with little to nothing programming knowledge, so that they will report a warning like this one).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `var<xx>` variables are all multiples of ten, i.e. there are no other variables beginning with `var`, you can use the colon-operator, which acts as a wildcard, e.g.

```
  drop var: ; /* drop all variables beginning with 'var' */
```

Alternatively, you can dynamically generate a list of all the variables :

```
proc sql noprint ;
  select name into :VARLIST separated by ' '
  from dictionary.columns
  where libname = 'WORK'
    and memname = 'HAVE'
    and compress(name,,'ka') = 'VAR'
    and mod(input(compress(name,,'kd'),8.),10) = 0 /* convert var<xx> to xx and check divisible by 10 */
  order by name ;
quit ;

data want (drop=&VARLIST) ;
  set have ;
run ;
```

Comment: not exactly what I want but works on this case, thx ! I assume there is nothing better ?

Comment: I've added a dynamically-derived solution to my answer above.

Comment: The dynamic solution will not only remove `var<divisible by ten>`, but also other columns divisible by ten, like `keep<divisible by ten>`. This can be solved by adding `1 = index(name, 'var')` to the `where` clause.

Comment: Your suggestion would also include varname10, varname20, etc. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

You could keep your drop list as is and turn off the warning before the data step:

```
options dkrocond=nowarn;
```

Typically I would turn the warning back on right after the DATA step with the drop list.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see a good reason to not list each of the nine variables. Condensing text in your program can be nice, but in this case, you gain little and you lose clarity.

If you're concerned about "optimization" (your tag) then I would definitely avoid adding an extra step to your program, especially one that queries the dictionary tables.

If you want to do this (say you have 100+ variables to drop), just use a simple macro to create the list:

```
%macro varlist;
%do i = 10 %to 90 %by 10;
var&i
%end;
%mend varlist;
```

Then call the macro:

```
data want(drop=%varlist);
    set have;
run;
```

Comment: Point is also that this hypothetical technique (the var1-100 is useful whenyou do numerous simulations) coud have been used in other programs. With the solutions I have been presented, indeed I will probably list the variables.

Comment: @AnthonyMartin Good point. This would be useful if you had more variables. Also, I removed an extraneous semicolon from my answer.

Comment: I don't think a query to `dictionary.tables` should have a significant impact on timing of a program - we're talking a second or two.  Overall I think a data driven program is superior to a macro like this - but certainly there will be cases where this is appropriate.

Comment: @Joe I mention the dictionary tables only because they can be slow and OP mentioned "optimization." I disagree with implementing "data-driven" solutions when they're not needed. It seems like OP just wants to condense text similar to data set lists, but with different criteria than what `-` allows.

Comment: We'll have to agree to disagree then.  I prefer not to hardcode things like this - although certainly in one-off programs that's appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to drop any variables that all share a common prefix then you can just do as below (just be careful you don't have any variable that share the same prefix that you don't want to delete!):

```
data want(drop=var:);
    set have;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

*I've edited this post substantially from the original post to reflect Joe's comments.*

One other possible method is to use double-dash notation but this should be used with caution.

```
drop var10--var90;
```

To paraphrase Joe's comment:

> It drops every variable that occurs between those two variables in the
>   variable list (ie, from left to right as you look at the dataset, or
>   in varnum order in a proc contents output). Any variable between them
>   would be dropped, no matter what they start with.

The below example shows that the variable `x` will also be dropped as it exists between the variable v10 and v30 within the dataset.  A potentially dangerous result, but still a potential solution:

```
data x;
  v10 = 1;
  x = 'a';
  v30 = 1;
  drop v10--v30;
run;
```